# Remove non-alphabetic words from a sentence using regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Is it possible to remove words in a sentence that doesn't contain a-z letters? I've thought about negative look arounds but wasn't successful.

For example,

```
This is a 1-2-a3 sample 12 -- 7-8 sentence
```

becomes

```
This is a 1-2-a3 sample sentence
```

Assume all other punctuations were removed except dashes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would match those words which won't contain an alphabet.

```
(?<!\S)[^a-zA-Z\s]+(?!\S)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3uD4/1)

Just replace those matched words with an empty string to get your desired output. `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind which asserts that the match won't be preceded by a non-space character. `(?!\S)` negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't be followed by a non-space character.

Comment: use this `\s*(?<!\S)[^a-zA-Z\s]+(?!\S)` if you want to remove leading spaces also. https://regex101.com/r/zB3uD4/2

Comment: What's the difference between `(?=\s)` and `(?!\S)`? Also, wouldn't word boundaries be simpler?

Comment: @Crazysheep `(?=\s)` won't match the string which was present at the line end. But it `(?!\S)` will do the match. Just play with `[^a-zA-Z\s]+(?!\S)` regex against this `sentence 7-8` string.

Comment: Just in case someone is using R for the job: "(?<!\\S)[^a-z\\s]+(?!\\S)"

Comment: and he must need to enable `pert=T` parameter.